# How to connect SentiWordNet to RapidMiner?

Tags: rapidminer

SentiWordNet is a text file. In RapidMiner 'OpenWordNet Dictionary' can only be used to access only exe files. How can I extract the sentiment scores from SentiWordNet for further processing?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can.. with a little bit of code you can take the sentiwordnet score from the text file.
but the problem is each same word might have several different meaning.
in handling this you can simply take the average score or doing wordsense disambiguation